# Implement interface at client in the webservice class

Tags: c#, wcf

I have referenced a webservice in my project. I want to implement an interface in the webservice class object at client project. Is is possible ?

I have tried to implement the interface in the web service partial class in the same namespace. It did not work.
e.g

At Client Side

```
namespace ABCWebService
{
   public partial class MyWebServiceObject : IInterface
   {

   }
}
```

MyWebServiceObject is an object.

Now in Code When I try to cast the object into interface it doesn't work

e.g.

```
foreach(var item in e.Result)

{
    if(item is IInterface) // it doesn't go inside.
    { }
}
```

Any suggestions.

Also The interface is not accessible if I implement the interface at server project.

e.g.

```
public class MyWebServiceObject : IInterface
{

}
```

Now At client side How will I refer this IInterface ? It doesn't recognize.

Should I change in the reference file ?

Thanks.

Comment: What "did not work"? What error did you get?

Comment: I tried to cast the object in the interface but it is not casting like
(obj is IInterface)

Comment: Web service is just for consume and not to implement with service interface.

Comment: Prasad I have come across some circumstance I have multiple objects which are coming from web service and I have to convert those objects into one single object.

Comment: Please add some code of what you're trying to do on the client, what error you get, what you have on the server. It's hard to understand based on the information in the question.

Comment: @carlosfigueira Lets say Collection<Obj1> and Collection<Obj2> is coming from service. I have to convert those objects into a single object. So I have created an iterface IInterface which will have some properties which i will need for further operations. 
                var dataType = Obj1.GetType();
                if (dataType is IInterface)
                {
                    
                }
It is not casting into the interface

Answer (score 0):

Your object types should implement the interface, not the service. (unless you have a collection of services?)

Comment: MyWebService is an object only not a service.

Comment: "Collection<Obj1> and Collection<Obj2> is coming from service. I have to convert those objects into a single object. So I have created an iterface IInterface which will have some properties which i will need for further operations. var dataType = Obj1.GetType(); if (dataType is IInterface) { } It is not casting into the interface"

So Obj1 and Obj2 implements IInterface?
Then you should simply do this:
if(obj1 is IInterface) {}


- If this is not what you are asking, then I think you need to edit your original question, and add a complete method, showing what you try to do.

Comment: I am just worried If I implement the interface in the Obj1 and Obj2  in the service project. Will the interface be accessible in the client project

Comment: Ahh... now I get what you mean. This thread answers your question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8912803/interfaces-in-contract-on-client?rq=1)

Comment: it is exposing property of type interface but in my case the class is implementing the interface and I want to refer that interface at client side.

Answer (score -1):

Hey I caught the problem. I had mentioned wrong namespace. Instead of client service namespace I was using Server namespace.

I know it is very silly mistake. Sorry guys I bothered you.

Many more thanks for your time and suggestions.

For the people who gets stuck in the same condition, the above example will work. I mean you can implement the interface at client place under the same namespace.